Browser back button doesn't work with youtube videos
I am facing an issue where when I upload any YouTube video on a page or upload multiple videos in a carousal (AEM), the browser button just doesn't work. It doesn't take you to the previous page. Also in the browser history, you see multiple videos.
Also observed that I have to press browser back button multiple times to go to the previous page (depends on how many videos I have uploaded on my page).
Is anyone else facing this issue? Let me know your thoughts.
I tried searching the history api docs, also tried uploading images in the carousal instead of videos. It works with images

Please [edit] your question and add the code you're tried. The iframe does not control the browser history, so, you should be able to go back.

Not sure if this helps, if your youtube videos are playing automatically on page load, you might need to handle play on load, which might fix the issue

Autoplay is disabled so they are not playing on page load.
